# Is there a way to do this "do while"?

Tags: c#

I'm currently using Flexsim, which uses some kind of C#.
My problem is that I need to change port when 1000 items pass.

For example:

I have 2 processors but I can use one at a time.
Everytime 1000 items pass, I want to use the other processor.
Something like

```
double id = 1;
double count = count +1;
if(count < 1000)
{ 
id = 2 // to go to the other processor
count =0;
}
```

and I want it to stay in id = 2 until count reaches 1000 again.
Help please!

Comment: does
```do{id=2;count=0;}while(count<1000);``` work

Answer (score 0):

Something like this sounds like it would work?

```
double id = 1;
double count = 0;
do
{
    count = count + 1;
    if(count >= 1000) 
    {
        if(id == 1) 
        {
            id = 2;
        }
        else 
        {
            id = 1;
        }
        count = 0;
    } 
} while(true);
```

You can write this shorter with ternary operators:

```
double id = 1;
double count = 0;
do
{
    count = count + 1;
    if(count >= 1000) 
    {
        id = id == 1 ? 2 : 1;
        count = 0;
    } 
} while(true);
```

I wasn't sure how you were doing your loop, so I've assumed a while loop would work. You could swap that bit out and make it fit your needs.

Comment: they asked for do while instead although this seems slightly more complicated I don't know the reason they asked for do while though

Comment: Ah oversight on my part.

Comment: Updated to use a do while loop although it doesn't make much difference since I'm using while(true) (which is terrible but wasn't a huge amount of info to go on)

Comment: yeah I had to read the title again to realize I don't know if they actually care the difference but I did mine in that format as well